# Perl YAML::Syck encoded string, howto properly decode in Java using JYaml?

Tags: java, perl, yaml, jyaml

Using beanstalkd and putting a job in tube/queue that contains a hash that is YAML::Syck encoded (with $YAML::Syck::ImplicitTyping = 1).

I need some syntax help on the Java end, as to how to decode handle that string pulled from the beanstalkd job.  The Perl hash ends up being encoded as a YAML string that looks like this:

--- NameFirst
--- Mike
--- NameLast
--- Smith
--- DOB
--- 07/07/2007

These YAML records (as above) are only processed one at a time.  So, given that string above, how in the world do I get JYaml to read that in, and decode into an object class with methods like:

Customer.NameFirst
Customer.NameLast
Customer.DOB

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are doing Dump(%hash) where you should be doing Dump(\%hash).  The former dumps an independent list of alternating keys and values; the latter dumps the hash with each value being associated with a key, like:

```
---
DOB: 07/07/2007
NameFirst: Mike
NameLast: Smith
```

Comment: Yes, I was just about to edit my original question. My YAML string now looks exactly as you posted it.  Now, when I'm in Java and I grab the data using beanstalkd client:

            // Grab job data
            byte[] dstBytes = job.getData();

            // inside temp is exactly what you have above
            String person = new String(dstBytes);

How would my class definition and JYaml code look like to take that "person" YAML string, and have it respond to something like:

  System.out.println(Customer.NameFirst);

??  Thanks.

Comment: Dang it, sorry about the formatting.. no preview in the comments field.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider switching to SnakeYAML. I too generate YAML from Perl via YAML::Syck to be consumed by Java. I ran into some interop problems with JYaml where YAML::Syck was generating valid YAML that JYaml couldn't parse. Since switching to SnakeYAML the only interop problems I've had have been bugs in YAML::Syck. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450399/which-java-yaml-library-should-i-use/1863814#1863814) has more details on my [experience with SnakeYAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450399/which-java-yaml-library-should-i-use/1863814#1863814).